# What does custom properties type "Python" do?

Tags: python

I am trying to add custom properties to bones. I can understand what normal type properties does like Float,Integer,and Boolean but I don't know what "Python type" custom properties does.

I can execute python script there like driver expression does? I can't find  a good explanation for "Python type" custom properties. What it does in general?

If you know what it does, please tell me how to use it and give me an example.

I can finally make a Python type custom property.
I've made this Python type property

```
Type = Python
Property Name = Python
Value = bpy.context.scene.frame_set(50)
```

And when I pushed "OK" to make it, python command "bpy.context.scene.frame_set(50)"is executed and current frame is set as 50, and after that this Python property has "NONE" Value. Its text field is now emptied and grayed out and I can't touch it anymore. I still don't know how to use Python type custom property. It's just one-time python script launcher?

[image]

Comment: Have you seen this page in the Blender Manual? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/custom_properties.html It mentions Python about halfway down the page and also at the bottom of it. It also has a link to the Python API at the bottom. Maybe the example in the API can help you.

Comment: I've already read it and it says nothing about how to use and how to set it up. Can you make a Python type custom properties? I am trying to make it but it is changed to to other types always. I don't know how.

Comment: API doesn't  tell me how to use Python type property and that  we can have custom color properties when we set it up as type = Float Array  Subtype =  Linear Color or Gamma-Corrected Color......

Comment: Hello, could you elaborate on what you call a python "type" property ? All python properties are type properties by definition. The code snippet you posted doesn't seem like it should execute. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: I added a picture. that's the custom property I am talking about. Python type custom property, which I don't know how to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/custom_properties.html#python-access) says:

> Edit a Python data type directly, used for unsupported data types.

So it seems they are meant for storing any kind of data that is not "supported". You can indeed set the properties to be a Python dictionary for example:

[image]

And it does show up as Python property:

[image]

It can also link to all sorts of Blender data like objects or materials or any other kinds of data blocks:

[image]

However it appears it cannot be anything:

[image]

So maybe it's not complete yet and it might get to be more defined in the future versions.

Comment: seems like it's way over my head. I though it can be used like other properties type, but right now there is no manual to handle python type.. thank you for your comment anyway.

Comment: What do you mean "no manual to handle"? You just use them with Python when you need to store something attached to something else and when data type doesn't match any other type, it gets called "Python". It's common to use custom properties from scripts for all kinds of stuff, it's just that I don't think anybody cares a lot about what type of custom property they are. Property types are useful, because they can be treated differently, for example Float Array, Linear Color subtype will have color input with color picker popping up if you click it in the UI.

Comment: I should have said "tutorial."  I don't understand "the time when you need to store something attached to something else and when data type doesn't match any other type". If you don't care give me an example please.

Comment: If I am writing some sort of add-on and for example I want to save some list of materials per scene, let's say I have them on the active object and want to save them with current scene for next time I open the file because my add-on needs to remember them for some reason, I will just do `C.scene["my_custom_material_list_for_later"] = C.object.data.materials`. I never have to see, or set, or even be aware of the type of the custom property. I care when I want to use custom properties to control something, maybe use attribute in a shader and have custom color property available from the Sidebar.

Comment: Like [this](https://i.imgur.com/6t7g26l.png) That's convenient to use manually, without Python, because I can set color per object but use the same shader and I can conveniently access that in the 3d viewport. So that's where having custom properties is awesome and having different types makes a difference. I don't care about types when using Python because as long as they work, they mostly get set automatically, unless of course I would want to create them for the user to use.

Comment: then we can use it as a variable to store object path, right.? if it's just object path we don't need to care about its type.

Comment: Not sure I get what you mean exactly, but yes, it seems we can store various Blender objects/data blocks or lists of them amongst other things. I am not sure about the correct terminology here. You should probably post further questions as separate questions so you might get better answers that way.

Comment: ok thank you for you answer

Answer (score 1):

Custom properties type `Python` will execute any Python command in its `Value` that can be executed by the `PYTHON INTERACTIVE CONSOLE`.

[image]

[image]

I think It is used by addons that defines custom property using the `PropertyGroup` class and register it to any data type e.g. `bpy.types.Scene`

Since `bpy.context.scene.frame_set(50)` and `PointerProperty(type=XX_PG_custom_properties)` are internal python API.

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import PropertyGroup
from bpy.props import *


class XX_PG_custom_properties(PropertyGroup):
    
    name : StringProperty(default='Test')
    
    
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(XX_PG_custom_properties)
    
    bpy.types.Scene.custom = PointerProperty(type=XX_PG_custom_properties)
    

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(XX_PG_custom_properties)
    
    del bpy.types.Scene.custom
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```

[image]

Comment: OK, it will execute apparently, but it is not really meant for that as far as I understand.

Comment: I don't know how to use add-on related things but it sheds some light. thank you.